# AutoMapper version 5 mapping IDataReader

Tags: automapper, automapper-5

I'm trying to map from IDataReader into Person but I always get 0 results:
https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/874

Profile:

```
internal class ImportAddressProfile : Profile
{
    private readonly IContainer _container;

    public ImportAddressProfile(IContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;

        CreateMap<IDataReader, Person>();
       CreateMap<IDataReader, List<Person>>();
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Run:
...

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("FirstName", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(int));
dt.Rows.Add("John", 123);
dt.Rows.Add("Bob", 2);

IDataReader reader = dt.CreateDataReader();
List<Person> People = Mapper.Map<IDataReader, List<Person>>(reader);

// returns zero results
```

I've already tried adding nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/automapper.data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoMapper.Data is not supported in AutoMapper 5. I broke out that into its own repository, mainly because I don't use it and don't have the foggiest idea of what the code does. If you're interested in getting it working, I'm happy to accept a PR from anyone who gets it working with AutoMapper 5.

Comment: Did you add this feature to automapper 6. Can you please mention example for idatareader mapping with version 6

Comment: No it's broken out into a separate package.

Comment: Where I can find relevant details, we are using automapper in number of projects and we are going to continue with latest version, our main usage is Idatareader. Appreciate if you can point out how to use idatareader with automapper.

Comment: The repository is on GitHub.

Comment: I have downgraded to version 3.3.1, I cannot find a way to do it using latest release.

Comment: I'm working on a version for 6.1 atm. Will get 6.1, then a 1.0 release of AutoMapper.Data.